# iOS 6 ViewController frame issue after changing Navigation Controller Frame

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios6

I have a Navigation based application in which i have to reduce frame of Navigation controller.
In iOS 6 after reducing Navigation Controller frame by 50px, height of child view controller should be (480-64(Navigation Bar + Status Bar)-50(Height I have reduced)=366. But i am getting view controller height as 386px. These extra 20px of View Controller goes under Navigation Bar. Please refer attached image.

Can anyone help me why this issue occurs? In iOS7 it works fine.

Here is my sample code:
AppDelegate :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

    ViewController* vc =[[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    vc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    UINavigationController* navVC = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:vc];
    self.window.rootViewController = navVC;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(36, 36), NO, 0.0);
    UIImage *blank = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:blank forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    return YES;
}
```

In Button Click Event of View Controller:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    CGRect navFrame = self.navigationController.view.frame;
    navFrame.size.height -=50;
    self.navigationController.view.frame = navFrame;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you clipping the frame of the navigation controller and not the viewcontroller ?

Comment: I am reducing Navigation Controller Frame to add an Advertisement in Window.

Comment: please see my given answer . It will help you

Answer (score 0):

Because view controller bounds would depend on root view controller and you have a navigation controller which should be minimum 44 px. So iF you want to show advertisement then please reduce sub view content frame height not self.navigationController.view frame.

And add your advertisement view into Window. Don't try to reduce navigation or viewcontroller frame height. Try to reduce or adjust subviews height and coordinates. And add your advertisment into bottom of the window.

Try to add you advertisement view in this way

```
@interface HomeVC : UIViewController<GADBannerViewDelegate>
{
}

@property(nonatomic, strong) GADBannerView *adBanner;

@end

@implementation HomeVC
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
   // Initialize the banner at the bottom of the screen.
    CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(isIpad?20.0:0.0, isIpad?935.0:IS_IPHONE_5?518.0:430.0);

    //    // Use predefined GADAdSize constants to define the GADBannerView.
    self.adBanner = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:isIpad?kGADAdSizeLeaderboard:kGADAdSizeBanner origin:origin];
    self.adBanner.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    // Note: Edit SampleConstants.h to provide a definition for kSampleAdUnitID before compiling.
    self.adBanner.adUnitID = adMobKey;
    self.adBanner.delegate = self;
    self.adBanner.rootViewController = self;

     [self.adBanner loadRequest:[self request]];
}

- (void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)adView
{

    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] addSubview:self.adBanner];
}
@end
```

Let me if you still have any problem.

Comment: Hi Chandan, Thanks for reply. I didn't understand "sub view content frame height". Do you mean i should reduce my viewcontroller's height instead of navigation controller height?

Comment: Hi Chintan, please don't reduce both viewcontroller's height and navigation controller height because it would be fixed as per window height. Just add your advertisement view at bottom of the window. And if advertisement view overlapping content of your view then try to set frame or constraint of your sub components of viewcontroller's.

Comment: Hi Chandan, I wanted to control this advertisement from app level, so i want an approach so that i don't have to change code of any view controller, that's why i am trying to reduce frame of Navigation Controller.

Answer (score 0):

To display advertisements you do not need to clip your view controllers view. Apple provides the ability to add advertisements banners in your app. Please take a look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/iAd_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009881-CH1-SW1)

Also be sure to read the [Best Practices](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/iAd_Guide/WorkingwithBannerViews/WorkingwithBannerViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009881-CH4-SW14)

Also take a look at the [iAdSuite](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/iAdSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010198) which provides great samples of including advertisements in your app.
This should take you in the right direction. I hope this helps

Comment: In iAdSuite examples, they have reduced ViewControllers frame & added AdView. Though UIViewController iAd Additions is a good alternative but it is only available in iOS7. And in my case i am not going to use iAd so can not use iAd Additions.

Comment: If you are talking about the banner example, please observe carefully that they have changed the frame of the _contentView and not the Viewcontrollers' frame.

Comment: Yes, Prathamesh they have change contentView's frame. But in my case whole app is developed, so i can not add a new ContentView in every view controller & i want an approach so that i can show banner ad without changing code of any view controller.

Comment: Understood.. But i would still advise against changing the navigation controllers frame. You can add the banner view as a subview of your individual view's or can follow what @chandan has suggested. You would have to manage the height of the banner view in your existing code, anything hidden behind it etc. Certain changes are inevitable.